# docker images show only None

Tags: docker

After relocate the docker image folder, I saw all of them become :

```
<none>       <none>    12069d4ba8d4   13 months ago   7.19GB
<none>       <none>    519d8684c235   20 months ago   5.93GB
<none>       <none>    12764c392d35   20 months ago   3.77GB
<none>       <none>    1c4919a8822c   20 months ago   111MB
<none>       <none>    a0d006d9b891   20 months ago   129MB
<none>       <none>    d87ab6bd211a   20 months ago   2.9GB
<none>       <none>    10b8f2a80a31   20 months ago   1.85GB
<none>       <none>    f643c72bc252   22 months ago   72.9MB
<none>       <none>    caaeaf912e18   2 years ago     1.96GB
<none>       <none>    c165f07c5dfb   3 years ago     4.47GB
<none>       <none>    7682fa2ad1a5   3 years ago     1.53GB
<none>       <none>    4ab4c602aa5e   4 years ago     1.84kB
<none>       <none>    a6e93ac09154   4 years ago     1.78GB
```

They are still usable but all the names and tags are gone. How to recover them?

Comment: What do you mean "relocate the docker image folder"? Can you elaborate? Which directory did you move?

Comment: @jkr docker image folder is pointed, so called relocated right?, to another folder by modifying daemon.json under /etc/docker, see https://www.guguweb.com/2019/02/07/how-to-move-docker-data-directory-to-another-location-on-ubuntu/

Comment: I'd delete the (relocated) corrupted `/var/lib/docker` directory entirely, and `docker pull` or `docker build` the images again.  This doesn't really seem to be a programming-related question, though.